# How can I get GRUB to configure my screen properly?

Tags: grub, boot-loader, display-settings

My screen says that it can't display the stream, and to use 1680x1050@60Hz as soon as grub would be loaded. I was told by #hardware on irc.freenode.net that this was due to grub missconfiguring the screen. I've haven't found anything whatsoever in the GRUB docs. Google talks about apparently outdated software like BURG. How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting resolution dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on what version of GRUB you are using. If you are using GRUBv1 as far as I know there is no way to change the resolution of that screen.
If, however, you are using GRUB2 there is a way to make that change.

To do so, first run the command `hwinfo --framebuffer` as root. You may not have it installed, so go ahead and install it, then run it (remember as root!).

After running that command you will see the VBE supported resolutions that you can use. Find one that fits your screen and remember it.

Next, edit your `/etc/default/grub` and remove the comment from the line `GRUB_GFXMODE` and put the resolution you chose in the last step.

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x600
```

Finally update grub by running `update-grub` as root to have it apply.

Reboot and enjoy the correct size!

Sources:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/grub-wrong-resolution-4175430150/#post4795547

http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Splashimages.html#Boot_Menu_Resolution_

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the detailed answer! Now fedora itself won't boot, though.

Comment: I am not exactly sure if that would be related, however if you reset the `/etc/default/grub` file to the default does that fix the issue?

Comment: No, it almost definitely doesn't have anything to do with it. I'll post a question about latter today. BUt thanks for incredible help, though!