# Fedora 17 not booting

Tags: fedora, boot, kernel-panic

I just got GRUB to properly set the resolution, thanks to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/how-can-i-get-grub-to-configure-my-screen-properly#comment69832_49837) wonderful answer. After selecting Fedora 17 and waiting a bit, this displays:

```
[   0.752888] [Firmware Bug]: powernow-k8: No compatible ACPI _PSS objects found.
[   0.752888] [Firmware Bug]: powernow-k8: Try again with latest BIOS.
```

(These two have dissappeared since enabling the Cool'n'Quiet BIOS setting)

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
[     0.758649] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000100
[     0.758649]
[     0.758980] Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 4.5.4-1.fc17.i686 #1
[     0.758306]  [<c093bb4b>] panic+0x81/0x17b
[     0.758455]  [<c043edfc>] do_exit+0x7fc/0x800
[     0.758612]  [<c043f094>] do_group_exit+0x34/0xa0
[     0.758649]  [<c043f118>] sys_exit_group+0x18/0x20
[     0.758649]  [<c094b2df>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
```

Knoppix and Fedora live boots work fine, though. Anything I short reinstalling Fedora I can to do to fix this?

What other specs or information would be needed?

Comment: Would [this posting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1147272#p1147272) help?

Comment: @Alex: How does one install a package in this context?

Comment: I'd first try to enable the 'Cool 'n Quit' feature in the BIOS and see if you can boot at all. If that's doesn't make your system boot so that you can't install that package, I'd say boot from a CD, mount the root-FS, chroot to it, mount all other filesystems and then install that package.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks, what are those other FS that should be mounted, exactly? And as far as I understand that's a kernel package - will yum install amd-ucode cut it?

Comment: Well, boot from CD. Mount your root-FS to, for instance, /mnt. Do a `chroot /mnt`. Then try `mount -a` or mount everything you can find in `/etc/fstab`. In theory - and if you booted a kernel which is the same architecture than the system you have installed on your harddrive - you can run yum.

Comment: `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt; chroot /mnt; mount -a; yum install microcode_ctl`. Cool'n'Quiet enabled in BIOS. Error persists, sans the first two lines.

Comment: @Alex: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6035/discussion-between-glycan-and-alex)